# Process one .tex file before the others (chemscheme)

Tags: chemistry, bpchem

I am using Chemscheme to track my compound numbers (I have a different .tex file for each chapter). The numbers need to be generated sequentially for the chemistry chapter (chapter 3) of my thesis but I would like to refer to (and have structures of) them in my earlier chapters (Chapters 1 and 2).

Is there a way to process the chapter3.tex file to generate the chemscheme numbers first but still have chapters 1 and 2 appear first in my final document?

I guess the alternative would be to generate a `\CNlabelnoref{}` list at the beginning of the intro chapter to define all the numbers before I say a word....

Comment: As information to others: it looks like you're actually using `bpchem` for the numbering. `chemscheme` doesn't provide a mechanism of its own.

Comment: If you just use `\CNref` in your earlier chapters you should be fine... They can be inserted into EPS files with `\psfrag` directly if you need that

Comment: what do you mean inserting \CNrefs into PSfrag? is doing that going to be a lot of effort? if so I may just do a \CNlabelnoref{} before my 1st chapter...

Comment: I blindly assumed (your question doesn't tell) that you want to use `\schemeref{foo}`. This esentially is equivalent to `\psfrag{TMP1}[b][b]{\schemerefformat{\CNlabel{foo}}}` (only with the `TMP1`, `TMP2` and so on generated automatically). So in the earlier schemes you *could* use `\psfrag{TMP1}[b][b]{\schemerefformat{\CNref{foo}}}` (note the use of `\CNref` here) instead of `\schemeref{foo}`. One could also define a new command analoguous to `\schemeref` for these cases. if I'm on the right track here I'll post an answer with a suggestion.

Comment: yes that sounds like exactly what I want to do. Ideally it would be a new command for \schemerefnotnew (or something similar) that acts as \schemeref replacing the eps text with the compound reference number but only uses the list of known \CNlabels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I gathered from question and comments:

1. the package `chemscheme` is used with `tracking=bpchem` (the mention of `\CNlabelnoref{}` was a hint)
2. Compound references before chapter 3 should only be references which means new labels should only be created in chapter 3 and later. `bpchem`'s labels are created *and* referenced with `\CNlabel{}`. The command for *only* referencing is `\CNref{}`.
3. A common use of `chemscheme` together with referencing compounds is the macro `\schemeref` which is used to replace text markers in EPS graphics with the corresponding label. However, since it internally uses `\CNlabel{}` it is cannot be used in chapters 1 and 2.

Proposed solution:

Define a `\schemeref`-like macro which uses `\CNref{}` instead of `\CNlabel{}`. `\schemeref`'s definition is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\schemeref[2]
  [\schemerefmarker\the\cst@ref@count]{%
  \advance\cst@ref@count\@ne\relax
  \psfrag{#1}[b][b]{%
    \schemerefformat{\cst@ref@label{#2}}%
  }%
}
```

You can

1. just copy this definition and exchange `\cst@ref@label` with `\CNref`:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \DeclareRobustCommand*\schemeonlyref[2]
     [\schemerefmarker\the\cst@ref@count]{%
     \advance\cst@ref@count\@ne\relax
     \psfrag{#1}[b][b]{%
       \schemerefformat{\CNref{#2}}%
     }%
   }
   \makeatother
   ```
2. or you can load the `xpatch` package and the `letltxmacro` package, make a copy of `\schemeref` and patch that:

   ```
   \usepackage{xpatch,letltxmacro}
   \makeatletter
   \LetLtxMacro\schemeonlyref\schemeref
   \xpatchcmd\schemeonlyref{\cst@ref@label}{\CNref}{}{}
   \makeatother
   ```

   (`\LetLtxMacro` is necessary because `\schemeref` is defined as robust macro and a simple `\let` wouldn't suffice. For the same reason `xpatch`'s `\xpatchcmd` instead of `etoolbox's`\patchcmd` is necessary.)